# website login/session managment

Tags: php, mysql, session

so i have been playing with this website of mine for over a year and still have very little understanding of session management.

i had a login script somewhere but thats hidden from me, not an issue though il find it.

but obviously without a session manager of some kind login is worthless.

i had a little idea the other day and drew a pretty flowchart on ways i can setup security.

but mysqli is slowing me down.

I had the idea to store a username in a cookie, this value can be compared with the database to find the last used session ID then compare that with the phpsesid cookie and finally refresh the id to something new and replace that in the db, this would mean anyone with an outdated session token would have to log back in, blah blah, sorry il get to the point.

so while building the new session manager im having issues pulling data from mysql

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
        require_once ("bin/sql.php");
        //plan to put another if statement here when the sql works
        $sql = "SELECT '$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]' FROM DB.TBL;";
        echo $sql . "<br>"; //debugging
        $uiddb = new sqlflow;
        $uiddb-> db_query($sql);
```

for debugging i have substituted the $sql to select a predefined username in the db, there will eventually be an 'if generic user, do other'.

the sql doc is abit of a mess, i have tried a few different variations after searching google, but common results are 'can not convert to string', unknown index, and even trying to pull as an array isnt working

```
mysqli_fetch
mysqli_store
misqli_use
```

all return 'expected 1 peram found 0'
and when i use the results var 'expected peram to be mysqli'
i have even taken the contents of the var and used it as the peram, thats when i seem to get the undefined index

```
function db_query($value){
    $connect = self::db_connect();
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$value);
```

i have not been able to get anything after this to work.

what im trying to do is pull info from database such as the PID+SESID of the user, so i can query the other 2 tables for further information such as last known IP.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT '$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]' FROM DB.TBL;";` This code is **dangerous**. Look into SQL injection vulnerabilities, and how to make a prepared statement in PHP.

Comment: this is alpha, im working on making it work, il be installing the real_escape later to secure against code injection EDIT, i already have a function designated to escape inputs before i run a query, but im taking it one step at a time. im working with XAMPP so need to worry about security while im the only person with access

Comment: That's a **dangerous** practice. Do it right the first time, so you don't forget to fix it, and so you don't train yourself to deprioritize security.

Comment: thanks for the input, il take it into account, right now when i cant even get the function to work there is no need to add more that interfere with the work, i have a work flow, per section, error handling then the functions task, then secure it, i cant forget in this instance as the security is on the flow chart, but your correct in other instances i may forget and should learn to prioritize differently

Comment: You really should consider using a framework like Laravel. Frameworks make it easy to write this sort of code - they'll have built-in session and database functionality - *and* they make it hard to write *in*secure code.

Comment: im sorry, im more then willing to take criticism about my work, but you should also consider that not everyone works the same way as you, everyone writes code in different ways, my way is not be berated by you because you do it differently, keep your criticism constructive, and when its explained that i have my own way of doing it and that my code excluding this portion is secure, and this piece will also be secure when im finished, accept it and move on, do not continue to badger me because you believe i am incorrect. just get over it and find somewhere else to throw around your comments, thx

Comment: Hey, it's your funeral. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's your problem. But here some examples how to use mysql connection in php:

**Database**

For your DB-connection you can use a single file.

```
/* db-connect.php */
<?php

# Neue Verbindung: Diese Variable kann global aufgerufen werden
$verbindung = new mysqli('db-server-adress', 'database-user', 'userpassword', 'database');

if($verbindung->connect_error)
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $verbindung->connect_error);
}

# Über diese Funktion können vereinfacht MySQL-Befehle abgesetzt werden
function query($sql)
{
    global $verbindung;

    if($result = $verbindung->query($sql)) 
    {
        return $result;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $verbindung->error;
    }
}
?>
```

Now everywhere you need a connection to your database you can include this file:

```
 /* Include the Database-Connection */
include 'db-connect.php';
```

With this you can call ths function "query" with every query you want to send to your mysql-db:

```
/* with the function query() you can call any sql-statement and box the result to a variable */
$queryresult = query("SELECT iduser FROM tbluser WHERE username='testuser';");

/* num_rows is the numbers of rows that were found by your query: */
if($queryresult->num_rows != 0)
{
     /* Fetch each found row of the query */
     while($fetchedQuery = $queryresult->fetch_assoc())
     {
           /* Call a single attribute from the current fetched row */
           echo $fetchedQuery['iduser'];
     }
}
else
{
     echo 'no result';
}
```

**Cookie**
I suggest to you to first box the result of your cookiename. But remember it's a vulnerability to store privat information in cookies:

```
session_start();
$cookie_name = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

if(!empty($cookie_name))
{
     $resultcookie = query("SELECT iduser FROM tbluser WHERE  username='$cookie_name';");

     if($resultcookie->num_rows != 0)
     {
          $fetchedcookie = $resultcookie->fetch_assoc();
          /* Create a new session with the username in it */
          $_SESSION['user'] = $fetchedcookie;
     }
     else
     {
          echo 'Cookie not found';
          ////// More Code /////
     }
}
```

Session Put the function session_start() at the top of every document:

```
<?php
session_start();

/* Check if the Session user exists with this client */
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
      echo 'Session is set';
}
else
{
      echo 'session is not set';
}

/////////// Destroy a Session ///////////
session_destroy();
```

Comment: you know, i thought i was going wrong in the query i was sending but the i couldn't brain it. great answer, let me just go other it and il accept it once i have no further questions

Comment: @L.H. Added some session management. The rest you gotta learn yourself.

Comment: You dont have any error-handling in your function. An error can always occur.

Comment: thanks @Oliver im still having issues with getting a usable response back from the query function, but the errors are not there so il just have to keep digging myself and find that myself. but very helpful, thank you sir

Comment: i have error handling everywhere, i always start with error handling then build the script so if there is a problem i get something back,  but obviously i have not put my entire code here.

Comment: Take some looks at w3schools : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp
 It's easy explained. Please mark this answer as correct so your question is closed. If you have another specific question feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: db connection has been setup for months, that was easy though sources like w3schools, it never changes so there is plenty of solid data on it, but querys change all the time so there is loads that can go wrong